# SSAS Cube Errors, Not Deploying

Tags: sql-server, ssas, cube, bids

I'm getting two errors which are very vague.

```
Internal error: The operation terminated unsuccessfully.
Server: The operation has been cancelled.
```

This occurs when I try to deploy the cube to the server.

Does anyone know how to fix this error?

Thanks,
Ethan

EDIT:
I just processed each dimension individually and all but one processed successfully.
I also have this one warning message that is suspicious

```
Errors in the OLAP storage engine: The attribute key cannot be found when processing: Table: 'dbo_DimPractice', Column: 'Phone', Value: '(111) 111-1111 ‎'. The attribute is 'Phone'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So The problem was that there were duplicate phone numbers with different phone numbers. I fixed this by changing the key on the attribute column to include the other attributes.

After fixing that, I had the same warning come up for my time dimension and I did the same thing for it, and then it deployed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Re-apply the service account if it was working earlier & restart the service of SSAS it will starts working.

Comment: Please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help) it will be useful to lift your content quality up